# Change Connection String from Application B for Application A

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have developed a WinForms application and I'm using Linq-To-Sql and I deployed it using ClickOnce. Now I want to develop a second WinForms application that is going to have only one Form and to be used for changing the Connection String for the first application. The question is: How can I change Connection String for the first application from the second application?

Note: I want to publish the second application with ClickOnce, too.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is storing Your connection string in external file (if You mind security of this solution, You can encrypt whole string).

Comment: Why not having a command line argument so that your first application can change its own connection string and just include that form from the other application into your first one?

Comment: Is this so hard to google proper question? Look here: [link](https://www.google.pl/search?q=change+connection+string+in+linq-to-sql&gws_rd=cr&ei=vumFV7TJFsawsAHNrLCoDQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, How about if you are going to change the first connection string from current setup connection string to registry connection string. if the connection string is in the registry, you can update it anytime you want, even in your second project..

Second thing is.. you can use the connection string anytime you want but the important is all of your project is in one pc only.

Try this one: No need to use app.config file

Note: add reference Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
     using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
    namespace registryConnection
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void SaveConnectionString()
        { 

            Interaction.SaveSetting("Projectname", "Connection", "Default",       Fullset_of_your_connection_string);
            Interaction.SaveSetting("Projectname", "dbname", "Default", dbname);
            Interaction.SaveSetting("Projectname", "uname", "Default",     dn_uname);
            Interaction.SaveSetting("Projectname", "pass", "Default",     db_password);
        }
        protected void getConnectionString()
        {
            Interaction.GetSetting("Projectname", "Connection", "Default", "");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It should be a comment.